# jquery .submit() method doesn't reaload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that i want to submit it throughout jquery .. but submit method doesn't send the request or reloading the page. any help?

in the html code there is no `<form></form>` tags , just text box and `<button></button>`

```
                $('#search_btn').click(function() {
                          e.preventDefault();
                    if ($('#search_txtbx').val().length > 0) {
                        $('<form action="<?= base_url('search'); ?>" method="POST">' +
                                '<input value="ls_subject" name="table" type="hidden">' +
                                '<input value="<?= $type; ?>" name="type" type="hidden">' +
                                '<input value="' + $('#search_txtbx').val() + '" name="search_string" type="hidden">' +
                                '</form>').submit();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The `form` element is never appended to the DOM so the submit event cannot be called on it. If you want to post data, there are better methods than this though, `$.ajax` being the first.

Comment: Why not just have this form in the body of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the form to the **DOM**, then submit the form :

```
$('#search_btn').click(function() {
 if($('#search_txtbx').val().length > 0) {
  $("body").append('<form style="display:none;" action="<?= base_url('search'); ?>" method="POST" id="bghdfrm">'+
   '<input value="ls_subject" name="table" type="hidden">' +
   '<input value="<?= $type; ?>" name="type" type="hidden">' +
   '<input value="'+$('#search_txtbx').val()+'" name="search_string" type="hidden">' +
   '</form>');
  $("#bghdfrm").submit();
 }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: what does `return false;` do here ?

Comment: @MajedDH It's the same as e.preventDefault(); but better.

Comment: @Subin How is it better?

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WAQCL/)

```
$('#search_btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#search_txtbx').val().length > 0) {
        $("body").append('<form style="display:none;" action="<?= base_url(search); ?>" method="POST" id="bghdfrm">' +
            '<input value="ls_subject" name="table" type="hidden">' +
            '<input value="<?= $type; ?>" name="type" type="hidden">' +
            '<input value="' + $('#search_txtbx').val() + '" name="search_string" type="hidden">' +
            '</form>');
        $("#bghdfrm").submit();
    }
});
```